# Spring 4.3 Implicit Constructor Injection Behavior On Lazy Component

Tags: java, spring

One of the new features in Spring 4.3 is [implicit constructor injection](https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3) in which we don't have to specify `@Autowired` anymore on top of the constructor.

My question is, how does the implicit constructor injection behave on lazy bean?

```
@Component
@Lazy
public class SomeClass {}

@Component
public class ClientClass {
    // does SomeClass still lazily initialized???
    public ClientClass(SomeClass someClass) { ... } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've applied the annotation *to the bean*, which means that Spring will create a lazy proxy and inject it where `SomeClass` is required. The fact that the bean requirement comes from an implicit (singleton) constructor doesn't matter.

Comment: They'll need a `@Scope` with `proxyMode` set to `TARGET_CLASS` (or `INTERFACES` with appropriate changes) to get the proxy behavior.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's orthogonal to the question of whether the laziness is applied based on how the dependency is expressed.

Comment: Maybe, but it's false to bring up the lazy proxy in this context because there won't be one. The `SomeClass` bean will be initialized completely in order to be injected into the constructor.